# Springfox Swagger SSO and calls another custom function

Tags: java, single-sign-on, swagger, springfox

I have created my Swagger Configuration with SSO to my AD Server like as shown below. When the user click the authorize button, he can navigate to the corresponding place to do authentication and gets the **id_token** and redirects and gives it to swagger where **id_token** will be passed on all API request header as bearer token.

[image]

Things are working fine but the issue is that I instead of id_token I need another token to be passed in the header of all API requests. I have a custom function called `getApiTokens` which gives another token based on the **id_token** passed as its input parameter. The newly created token returns from the `getApiTokens` function has to be passed on all API header as bearer

[image]

Can anyone please help me on this

I am using **springfox-swagger2** for my project

My **SwaggerConfig.java** code is shown below

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Configuration config;

    @Bean
    public Docket userApi() {
        final List<ResponseMessage> list = Lists.newArrayList();
        list.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(401).message("Unauthorized").responseModel(new ModelRef("Result"))
                .build());;

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("omnesys-api").apiInfo(apiInfo()).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.omnesys.api")).paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().securitySchemes(newArrayList(oauth())).securityContexts(newArrayList(securityContext()))
                .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET, list).globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.POST, list);
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Omnesys API")
                .description("Omnesys API")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("https://omnesys.com/service").contact(contact()).license("Apache License Version 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("https://omnesys.com/service/LICENSE").version("2.0").build();
    }

    private Contact contact() {
        return new Contact("Omnesys", "https://omnesys.com", "admin@omnesys.com");
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityContext securityContext() {
        final AuthorizationScope readScope = new AuthorizationScope("read", "read your admin");
        final AuthorizationScope[] scopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        scopes[0] = readScope;
        final SecurityReference securityReference = SecurityReference.builder().reference("omnesys_auth").scopes(scopes)
                .build();
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(newArrayList(securityReference)).build();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityScheme oauth() {
        return new OAuthBuilder().name("omnesys_auth").grantTypes(grantTypes()).scopes(scopes()).build();
    }

    List<AuthorizationScope> scopes() {
        final List<AuthorizationScope> scopes = Lists.<AuthorizationScope>newArrayList();
        scopes.add(new AuthorizationScope("resource-access", "Get Resource Access"));
        return scopes;
    }

    List<GrantType> grantTypes() {
        final GrantType grantType = new ImplicitGrantBuilder()
                .loginEndpoint(
                        new LoginEndpoint(config.getSecurity().getOauth2().getClient().getUserAuthorizationUri()))
                .build();
        return newArrayList(grantType);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityConfiguration securityInfo() {
        return new SecurityConfiguration("97aaf5ff-b64d-4ec2-a409-b434d7744930", "d3cc95e9-6ed8-448f-a448-1ab02b72967e", "swagger", "swagger", "", ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER, "", " ");
    }
}
```